# Could not get any response from dockerized Flask web API

Tags: docker, http, flask, docker-compose, flask-restful

I am building a `web API` using `Flask` on a `Windows 10` machine. The application works just fine on local. So I decided to dockerize it before the poject get bigger.
This is the structure of the application:

```
Application
|- docker-compose.yml
|- web
  |- Dockerfile
  |- requirements.txt
  |- app.py
  |- ...
```

When I build the stack of images (in this case I have only one) and I launch the container, it looks like the container behave correctly. But once I try to access the `API` from `Postman` or a web browser, the application refuse any connexion.

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: ./web
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

and this is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

for the file `app.py`, this is the interesting part of it:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

`Docker` output that the app is running on `http://0.0.0.0:5000/` but I can't make any request to the API neither on `http://0.0.0.0:5000/` or `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` or even `localhost:5000/`.

Comment: With your service running, can your run the following and see if your app responds? `docker-compose exec web curl http://localhost:5000`

Comment: @Mihai That's actually strange. It does work running this command, but not from `Postman` or the browser.

Comment: Then it should work. Open a shell in the running container and make sure the your host is actually set to 0.0.0.0 (maybe you run on an old image). If that is not the case then can you double check your code and make sure it is correct?

Comment: @Mihai The code works just fine without docker and it works just fine inside the container. I made also sure it runs on `0.0.0.0:5000`

Comment: I just saw you are on Windows.... :) What are you using VirtualBox or HyperV? Docker runs in a VM so you need to map port 5000 from that VM to your host.

Comment: @Mihai Yes I had to work on `Windows` lol. I am using `HyperV` to make `Docker` works on my computer. So shouldn't the port mapping be done automatically ?

Comment: As far as I not it doesn't work automatically. I am also not a Window expert, sorry :) But from what I remember that's where your problem is